# Is there a bug with nested invoke of LambdaExpression?

Tags: c#, lambda

I tried to compile and calculate LambdaExpression like:

> Plus(10, Plus(1,2))

But result is 4, not 13.

Code:

```
using System;
using System.Linq.Expressions;

namespace CheckLambdaExpressionBug
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] _args)
        {
            ParameterExpression p1 = Expression.Parameter(typeof (int), "p1");
            ParameterExpression p2 = Expression.Parameter(typeof (int), "p2");
            LambdaExpression lambda = Expression.Lambda(Expression.Call(typeof(Program).GetMethod("Plus"), p1, p2), p1, p2);

            InvocationExpression exp1 = Expression.Invoke(
                lambda,
                Expression.Constant(1),
                Expression.Constant(2)
                );

            InvocationExpression exp2 = Expression.Invoke(
                lambda,
                Expression.Constant(10),
                exp1
                );

            var func = (Func<int>) Expression.Lambda(exp2).Compile();

            int v = func();
            Console.Out.WriteLine("Result = {0}", v);
        }

        public static int Plus(int a, int b)
        {
            return a + b;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Tried it with VS2010: Result = 13

Comment: If you target .NET 3.5 (even in VS2010) then you'll get "Result = 4"; If you target .NET 4 then you'll get "Result = 13".

Comment: Thank you very much. Yes, I use .NET 3.5.

Comment: So I conclude: yet it was a bug; yes it is fixed. I wouldn't necessarily anticipate a 3.5 back-fix though, unless there is another SP.

Comment: LukeH/Marc Gravell - perhaps one of you should write your comment as an answer - I'd feel wrong using your comments as my research for posting an answer.  Good find!

Comment: @LukeH would you please comeback and setup your comment as an answer?

Comment: You could find y-combinator interesting: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/madst/archive/2007/05/11/recursive-lambda-expressions.aspx

Comment: @kitafan: If nobody writes an answer, please do so yourself. I think you have an answer, and this question is contaminating the "unanswered" query results.

Answer (score 1):

Since nobody seems to be posting this:

It looks to be a bug in .NET 3.5, and is fixed in .NET 4.

Answer (score 0):

whereas this seems to produce 13 in 3.5 too:

```
     var plus = new Func<int, int, int>((a, b) => a + b);
     var func = new Func<int>(() => plus(10, plus(1, 2)));
     var res = func();
     Console.WriteLine(res);
```

Comment: You make too audacious supposition for the steps to reproduce it. Dont't stop, and try: int res = 10 + (1 + 2); You be amazed, it also return 13...
In question I gave a concrete example to reproduce a problem. There is no sense to analyze other situations.

Answer (score 0):

maybe i needs to assign the result to a local var
try this

var plus = new Func((a, b) => a + b); 
var puls_1 = plus(1, 2);
var func = new Func(() => plus(10, plus_1)); 
var res = func(); 
Console.WriteLine(res);